# UIWebView contentSize height on landscape issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, autolayout, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm facing a strange issue with UIWebView that on landscape, after I rotate the device from portrait its returns incorrect height. For portrait mode I'm returning the height and adjust the height of the UIWebView via constraint.

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    let url = request.URL

    if navigationType == .Other {
      if url?.scheme == "ready" {

        print((url?.host?.floatValue)!)

        webViewHeight.constant = (url?.host?.floatValue)!

        if (!observing) {
          startObservingHeight()
        }

        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  }
```

Please see my full implementation, the [entire View Controller class here](https://gist.github.com/alexszilagyi/b33de0bbd57e9426636c20d25d8ef64e) . Loaded HTML [can be seen here](https://gist.github.com/alexszilagyi/4871d007afc36ef99d9566fc31479f5f#gistcomment-1747330)

Comment: do you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Bumping this as it's still relevant in 2020

Comment: @Jabbar: ended up using a `UITextView `. Hope it helps